# Scatter Plot Using Matplotlib, "Autofilling" an Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a column of data loaded from a text document, and I am try into to make a scatter plot with it using matplotlib. I want to use the data from the text document as my y axis, and I want to have my x axis to be a whole number corresponding to my y axis. For example, my y axis could have a set of numbers like (34.10, 79.48, 600.52, -999.00, 1000.35...), and I would want my x axis to be (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...) with each one corresponding to one another. If anyone knows how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

[Screenshot of how I have python loading the data I want to have as my y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvFBF.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code; the code should be in your question as links can expire and it also makes it harder to replicate your issue. However, in this case, it's not clear to me why you couldn't just use `x = range(len(y))` as a substitute for something like the [scatter plot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) as a first-pass attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [34.10, 79.48, 600.52, -999.00, 1000.35]
plt.scatter(range(len(y)),y )
plt.show()
```

[image]